# docker-compose up stuck on "Attaching to ...."

Tags: docker-compose

I run the below command under the docker-compose.yml folder:

```
docker-compose up
```

my "docker-compose.yml" file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  ubuntu:
    image: "ubuntu:latest"
    tty: true
```

But the issue is:

```
Jianfengs-MBP:homedocker jianfengli$ docker-compose up ubuntu
Recreating homedocker_ubuntu_1 ... done
Attaching to homedocker_ubuntu_1
```

[My docker info(About docker)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjHF8.png)

Engine: 18.06.1-ce
Compose: 1.22.0

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behaviour. After attaching it goes to print logs, but if there are no logs then it just waits.

If you want up to exit use up `docker-compose up -d`